# Connect to host system Web API from Windows docker Container

Tags: docker, windows-container

I am running a web API on the host system and it's not exposed on public IP.
I want to access from a docker windows container running on the same system.

By initial analysis, it seems windows container does not support to access host system from within a container.

Tried to access API with the following address but on none of them are working.

```
https://host_system_ip:port/api/controller/action
```

```
https://default_gateway_ip:port/api/controller/action
```

```
https://localhost:port/api/controller/action
```

```
https://127.0.0.1:port/api/controller/action
```

For security reasons I cannot make that API to be accessed on public IP, the only host system and containers running on same host machine should be allowed to access web API.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me from within container. Make sure you are on latest OS etc and nothing is missing.

```
PS C:\> docker run --rm microsoft/windowsservercore powershell invoke-webrequest 192.168.1.221 -useBasicParsing


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : Application 995184 and started on 3/21/2018 8:59:09 AM
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Content-Length: 54
                    Cache-Control: private
                    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
                    Date: Wed, 21 Mar 2018 14:01:22 GMT
                    Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
                    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
                    X-Pow...
Forms             :
Headers           : {[Content-Length, 54], [Cache-Control, private],
                    [Content-Type, text/html; charset=utf-8], [Date, Wed, 21
                    Mar 2018 14:01:22 GMT]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        :
RawContentLength  : 54



PS C:\> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter vEthernet (nat):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::94d6:434:c0b6:8fdc%56
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.29.112.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Internet):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::342a:be30:c7c:c1de%24
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.221
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```